# Why are documents not deleted? deleteByQuery seucceds but does not delete anything

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my query that I execute using the `@elastic/elasticsearc` npm package.

```
client.deleteByQuery({
    index: "_all",
    body: "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "couchDbOrigin": "aed_storage_dd4d4860-6b3f-45ed-807e-91bb3c450c15"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  });
```

Here you can see some data that I would expect to be deleted:

[image: es rows containing data matched by the delete query]

I get a successful response from the ES server, but with no deletes:

```
 { body:
   { took: 1,
     timed_out: false,
     total: 0,
     deleted: 0,
     batches: 0,
     version_conflicts: 0,
     noops: 0,
     retries: { bulk: 0, search: 0 },
     throttled_millis: 0,
     requests_per_second: -1,
     throttled_until_millis: 0,
     failures: [] },
  statusCode: 200,
  headers:
   { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     'content-length': '215',
     'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true' },
  warnings: null,
  meta:
   { context: null,
     request: { params: [Object], options: [Object], id: 1 },
     name: 'elasticsearch-js',
     connection:
      { url: 'http://localhost:9200/',
        id: 'http://localhost:9200/',
        headers: {},
        deadCount: 0,
        resurrectTimeout: 0,
        _openRequests: 0,
        status: 'alive',
        roles: [Object] },
     attempts: 0,
     aborted: false } }
```

Why are the documents not deleted?

Comment: Could you share index mapping?

Comment: Try couchDbOrigin.keyword in the query

Comment: But you response say " deleted: 0,"